# Excellent Sample but Export to PDF doesn't work locally in Chrome

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I come across this beautiful example

```
plnkr.co/edit/xBvc4094CIu6oGDZXZx7?p=preview
```

When I download (changed // to http://) and run locally export csv works fine where as export to pdf doesn't work fine.

I suspect something needs to be enabled in Chrome browser or security settings.

Any idea what might be the issue? How to make it work in Chrome? Is there  any setting or configuration needs to be fixed?

Comment: Please elaborate, show errors, etc. I see nothing wrong with this..

Comment: It throws following in console via inspect element - pdfMake.js line:215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 26 :

```
pdfMake.createPdf(content).open();
```

Replace this line with this :

```
pdfMake.createPdf(content).download('your_pdf_name.pdf');
```

Comment: can u let me know the fixes to be made in the above example?

Comment: Thats what i said. Go to the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBvc4094CIu6oGDZXZx7?p=preview) 
Open app.js, goto line 26 and the replace the line with-
`pdfMake.createPdf(content).download('your_pdf_name.pdf');`